# Bundler in production not ignoring the development and test gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, passenger, bundler

I have a couple of rails websites in production on a ubuntu webserver of ours..

We're running Ubuntu 10.10 + Passenger and Apache.. and ruby enterprise edition version 1.8.7 (No RVM),

I've been having a problem with bundler on both the sites..

Whenever i restart the app by touching restart.txt or by rebooting the server, The user sees an error saying passenger could not be started because it couldn't find nokogiri (a requirement of one of the test gems) so i try and run 'bundle install' which fails cause it tries to install nokogiri..

I've tried running

```
bundle install --without development:test
```

And various other variations..

I think one of them worked until i restarted the app and we were back to square one again..

So for the moment i resigned myself to commenting out all gems in the development and test group..

Any ideas?

Thanks

Daniel

---

Oh i forgot to mention.. I'm deploying using capistrano :)

Comment: Are you using rails? If so, what version?

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide a space-separated list for the `--without` parameter, see http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-install.1.html

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a space. You should do:

```
bundle install --without=development:test
```

Comment: Don't you have to quote/escape the space (so that "development" isn't considered as a different/unrelated command-line argument)?

Comment: You're correct although I've usually seen it as `env1:env2:env3`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`bundle install --without development test`

or even:

`bundle install --path vendor/bundle --without development test`